# Outputting string to a text file from a batch program

Tags: string, variables, batch-file, dos

I'm looking to echo a piece of text input by the user from a batch file into a text file but I'm having some trouble: Every time the user enters the string and when the batch file closes, the text file is empty, almost like the variable was never set.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set /a num=%random% %%100 +1
SET /a nummod2=num %% 2
IF %nummod2% == 0 (
cls
echo Enter some Text!
set /p string=Text: 
echo Text="%string%" >> Log.txt
exit
) ELSE (
exit
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: But don't feel bad; literally everybody who programs in batch learns about delayed expansion the hard way.

Comment: I'm still a little confused, can you maybe please elaborate?

Comment: Change `setlocal` to `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and change `%string%` to `!string!`

Comment: I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/combining-all-mp4s-in-directory-with-ffmpeg/30284028#30284028) to be a great explanaition of the problem